# Cancel an asynchronous event in the async/await model

Tags: c#, events, async-await

My question is based on @aepot's answer to [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/261396/asynchronous-event-handler) question. How does cancellation work in this model? How is `CancellationToken` passed to the `InvokeAsync` method?

```
public static class DelegateExtensions
{
    public static Task InvokeAsync<TArgs>(this Func<object, TArgs, Task> func, object sender, TArgs e)
    {
        return func == null ? Task.CompletedTask
            : Task.WhenAll(func.GetInvocationList().Cast<Func<object, TArgs, Task>>().Select(f => f(sender, e)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How is CancellationToken passed to the InvokeAsync method?

It is not, if you want to support cancellation you would need to change the method to add such a parameter:

```
public static Task InvokeAsync<TArgs>(this Func<object, TArgs, CancellationToken , Task> func, 
    object sender,
    TArgs e, 
    CancellationToken cancel)
    {
        return func == null ? Task.CompletedTask
            : Task.WhenAll(func.GetInvocationList()
                    .Cast<Func<object, TArgs, CancellationToken, Task>>()
                    .Select(f => f(sender, e, cancel)));
    }
```

Cancelling needs to be done cooperatively, i.e. the actual method needs access to the cancellation token.

Comment: Thank you @JonasH. Instead of another parameter to InvokeAsync, how about using the TArgs instead? I'm thinking of creating a new AsyncEventArgs class with CancellationToken as a property. Would that be a good practice?